# Facebook application authentication cancel button issue in iPhone

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

How do I get to know when the cancel button is clicked from a Facebook appliaction in iPhone while authentication.

We can get the callback for other through delegate functions, but I don't know how to get the callback for the cancel button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook provides a delegate method which you can use:

```
- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled;
```

You have to implement `FBSessionDelegate` and this method will be called if the person clicks on the cancel button.